# Condensing Rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, primes

Let's say I have a table that for every new 'Item Bought' it recreates a row with all the same values except for the new Item and there are 1000 different items.

```
ID      Time    Date        Cashier Item Bought     
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob     Apple
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob     chicken
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob     eggs
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob     Banana
0002    12:30   16/1/27     Steve   Apple
0002    12:30   16/1/27     Steve   pork
0002    12:30   16/1/27     Steve   milk
```

What I'm trying to do is condense the rows in such a way that saves space but still allows me to search transactions by items.

Things I tried

**Bit Manipulation**

Assign each each bit to a item.

```
Item    Bit
Apple   1 (0000 0001)
eggs    2 (0000 0010)
Chicken 3 (0000 0100)
fish    4
Banana  5
pork    6
milk    7
.
.
.
(to 1000)
```

Change

```
ID      Time    Date        Cashier Item Bought 
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob     Apple
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob     chicken
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob     eggs
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob     Banana
```

Into

```
ID      Time    Date        Cashier     Items Bought                    
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob         0001 0111
```

I can do bitwise operations to check for items.

Check if transaction has apple and banana

```
0001 0111   Items Bought
0001 0001   Check = bits for apple and banana
```

Logic: if (~Check nor Items Bought == 0) (Include)

```
1110 1110   ~Check
0001 0111   Items Bought

0000 0000
```

Problem is you can only do bitwise operation up to 64 bits using BIGINT. I would need 1000 bits or 16 additional columns.

**Prime Numbers**

Assign a prime number based on how frequent an item is bought

```
Item    Bought  Assigned Prime
Apple   190893  2
eggs    150022  3
Chicken 71026   5
fish    59827   7
Banana  10274   11
pork    5271    13
milk    1021    17
.
.
.
(to 1000)
```

For each column multiply every prime together

change

```
ID      Time    Date        Cashier Item Bought 
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob     Apple
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob     chicken
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob     eggs
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob     Banana
0002    12:30   16/1/27     Steve   Apple
0002    12:30   16/1/27     Steve   pork
0002    12:30   16/1/27     Steve   milk
```

To

```
ID      Time    Date        Cashier     Items Bought
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob         330 (2 * 5 * 3 * 11)
0002    12:30   16/1/27     Steve       442 (2 * 13 * 17)
```

If I want to see which transactions have an item, divide column by that prime number. By the properties of prime, if the result is a whole number than the transaction does have that item.

Check if transaction has apple and banana

primeCheck = 22 (2 * 11)

Logic: If (Items Bought % primeCheck == 0) (Include)

```
ID      Time    Date        Cashier     Include
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob         YES     330 % 22 = 0 
0002    12:30   16/1/27     Steve       NO      442 % 22 = 2
```

Problem is, multiplying prime numbers get really big really fast. The reason why I would use this over bit manipulation is that with BM, I would need 1024 bits no matter the items.

**String Concatenating**

Change

```
ID      Time    Date        Cashier Item Bought 
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob     Apple
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob     chicken
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob     eggs
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob     Banana
```

Into

```
ID      Time    Date        Cashier     Items Bought                    
0001    12:00   16/1/26     Bob         Apple, chicken, eggs, Banana
```

Problem is the search complexity to iterate through each item bought string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This makes no sense to me at all. Are you trying to create a comma delimited list of item numbers purchased? Or something else entirely? This sounds like a classic XY Problem to me.

Comment: I think you should express the logic of what you're trying to do, and let the SQL engine handle the low-level details.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Okay let me fix my question. In gist I'm trying to condense my table in such a way where I save on time and computation

Comment: Do you actually have a performance issue when querying this table that you are trying to resolve? Or are you just trying to be proactive and come up a solution to solve a performance problem that doesn't exist?

Comment: I am getting performance issues but as I'm looking more into this I see your point. My queries run under a minute until I have to join with this table which takes over 20 minutes. I'm relatively new to SQL and under the assumption that condensing the data in this table will result in a much smoother join because I won't be dealing with the sheer volume but it might not be the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply normalize the table structure?
Something like the following perhaps...

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Personnel (
    PersonID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT pk_Personnel_PersonID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PersonID),
    PersonName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    );

CREATE TABLE dbo.Product (
    ProductID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT pk_Product_ProductID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ProductID),
    ProductName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    );

CREATE TABLE dbo.OrderHeader (
    OrderHeaderID INT NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT pk_OrderHeader_OrderHeaderID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (OrderHeaderID),
    OrderDT DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT df_OrderHeader_OrderDT DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
    CashierID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT fk_OrderHeader_Personnel_PersonID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Personnel(PersonID)
    );

CREATE TABLE dbo.OrderDetail (
    OrderDetailID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT pk_OrderDetail_OrderDetailID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (OrderDetailID),
    OrderHeaderID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT fk_OrderDetail_OrderHeader_OrderHeaderID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.OrderHeader(OrderHeaderID),
    ProductID INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT fk_OrderDetail_Product_ProductID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Product(ProductID),
    Quantity INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT df_OrderDetail_Quantity DEFAULT (1),
    Returned BIT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT df_OrderDetail_Returned DEFAULT(0)
    );

INSERT dbo.Personnel (PersonID, PersonName) VALUES (1, 'Bob');

INSERT dbo.Product (ProductID, ProductName) VALUES 
    (1, 'Apple'), (2, 'Chicken'), (3, 'Eggs'), 
    (4, 'Banana'), (5, 'Pork'), (6, 'Milk');

INSERT dbo.OrderHeader (OrderHeaderID, OrderDT, CashierID) VALUES 
    (1, '2016-01-26 12:00:00', 1), (2, '2016-01-26 12:00:00', 1);

INSERT dbo.OrderDetail (OrderDetailID, OrderHeaderID, ProductID, Quantity, Returned) VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2, 1, 0), (3, 1, 3, 12, 0), (4, 1, 4, 1, 0),
    (5, 2, 1, 2, 0), (6, 2, 5, 1, 1), (7, 2, 6, 1, 0);

--===============================================================

-- query that produces the original data...
SELECT 
    oh.OrderHeaderID,
    [Time] = CAST(oh.OrderDT AS TIME),
    [Date] = CAST(oh.OrderDT AS DATE),
    Cashier = p.PersonName,
    ItemBought = p2.ProductName,
    od.Returned
FROM 
    dbo.OrderHeader oh
    JOIN dbo.OrderDetail od
        ON oh.OrderHeaderID = od.OrderHeaderID
    JOIN dbo.Personnel p
        ON oh.CashierID = p.PersonID
    JOIN dbo.Product p2
        ON od.ProductID = p2.ProductID;
```